# getImageCount() always returns 1

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve the `int` value of how many images my device has in it's Gallery. I will be using this later to loop through and grab the images.

```
private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
        }

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp,
                        "picture", "a picture");
                Log.v("HEY", "Your image should be in the gallery now");                
                Log.v("IMAGES", "Number of Images: " + getImageCount());
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.v("CANCELED", "The user has canceled the activity");
            }
        }

    }

    public int getImageCount() {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Camera");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        int numberOfImages = files.length;
        return numberOfImages;
    }
```

However the logcat is posting this

```
06-19 18:24:41.380: V/HEY(5367): Your image should be in the gallery now
06-19 18:24:41.380: V/IMAGES(5367): Number of Images: 1
```

So it's telling me there is 1 image when the actual number of images is currently 14. I must be missing something simple, but I can't see it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IF you check the directory manually (via adb or something), what do you see?

Comment: @ninetwozero well if I simply go into the directory via connecting to my pc using usb there are 14 images. If you mean something else I'm not sure I know how to check that

Comment: That's what I meant. :) Try `Log.d()`:ing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Camera"` - you'd be surprised what magic you may find.

Comment: @ninetwozero it says `06-19 18:59:41.080: D/IMAGES(6344): /storage/emulated/0/Camera`. So what's that mean?

Comment: lol@ -1, for what? Why would this question be down voted? At least post the reason

Comment: @i_me_mine do you have a DCIM folder or anything inside of `Camera/`?

Comment: @FoamyGuy No there is nothing inside Camera but the actual pictures. Also Camera is inside DCIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, the comment from @FoamyGuy sparked an idea. If Camera is inside my DCIM, then I need to change this

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Camera");
```

to this

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");
```

This seems silly as I've never had to specify the DCIM folder before. It is what it is though, I hope this helps others.